# No Debug Symbols cross compile ARM on BusyBox

Tags: c, gdb, arm, cross-compiling, gdbserver

i'm trying to **debug a C program, which runs on an ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)**. The software was **cross-compiled** (and is statically linked) with the std. arm-linux-gnueabi compiler (intalled via synaptic). I run **Ubuntu 13.04 64bit**. On the device is a **Busybox v1.18.2**. I successfully compiled gdbserver (with **host=arm-linux-gnueabi**) and gdb (with **target=arm-linux-gnueabi**) and can start my program on the embedded device via the locally running gdb...
My problem now is, that i don't have a proper backtrace output.

### Message of gdb:

```
Remote debugging using 192.168.21.127:2345
0x0000a79c in ?? ()
(gdb) run
The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or "continue".
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00026628 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00026628 in ?? ()
#1  0x00036204 in ?? ()
#2  0x00036204 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

I try to compile the software with **-g, -g3 -gdwarf-2, -ggdb, -ggdb3** without any difference.

Has anybody an idea what i am missing here?

Is this a problem maybe with the BusyBox or do i need additional libs on my host system?

I also tried the function **backtrace_symbols** from **execinfo.h** with nearly the same output...

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Try to google *solib-absolute-prefix*, and use `file target.elf` on the remote host, so it has the symbol tables.  GDB by default does not transfer symbols from the remote, it expects you to have the symbols on the host debugger's file system..

Answer (score 0):

Another way for debugging is use gdb inside board follow below steps.

```
1)Run gdb process and attach your process to gdb using attach <pid> command
2)Continue your process using c command in gdb
```

Whenever you find any SIGINT or SIGSEGV then refer stack of your process using bt command in gdb.